# timeout in iframe causes scroll issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion, iframe, timeout

So I have an iframe embedded on a website in which a simple stop watch runs. It is nothing more than a recursive timeout. However the repetitive DOM changes made in there causes the content of the parent website to 'flicker' and the inner iframe website to jump to top. This makes scrolling on the iframe content impossible due to the immediate jumps to page top.

This problem seems to only appear in mobile browsers (tested in iOS Safari 10.3.2), whereas the duration of the interval is irrelevant (same problem when calling only every second).

**The recursive timeout**

```
$('#starttimer').on('click', function(e) {
    loopTimer = function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#time').text('change');  /* DOM modifications seem to be the guilty part */
            loopTimer();
        }, 1);
    }
    loopTimer();
});
```

Has anybody faced a similar issue or does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, as I already mentioned this seem to be a problem with the redrawing of the iframe's content and it only appears in iOS Safari browsers (and mobile Chrome browsers).

The problem was that the browser has issues to re-calculate the height of the iframe after the content changed in some way. To work around this bug, all I had to do was to

**A:** either assign 100% height on the iframe's html and body and make it able to overflow.

```
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

**B:** or calculate the outer iframe's height with javascript and write the value as inline-style on the iframe element whenever the inner content changed.

I hope this one helps to those who struggles with this iOS bug. Cheers.